# Pyinstaller compiled app closes instantly, then reopens & works (macOS)

Tags: python, tkinter, compilation, pyinstaller, customtkinter

I have compiled a Python script with a Tkinter GUI using Pyinstaller.

When trying to open my app, it adds the app to the dock for a split second, then closes it and reopens after about 10-20 seconds (Then it runs completely normal).

This only happens when I use the --onefile --windowed option, using --onedir --windowed the app just opens immediately and stays open.
I would prefer using my app as --onefile --windowed without it opening, closing, and reopening though.

[image: gif animation of application opening, closing and reopening]

My setup:
macOS (Ventura 13.1)
Python 3.9.18
PyInstaller 6.0.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2023.9

I tried all sorts of different PyInstaller options but I can't find the problem

In case it might help identify the problem, here is my PyInstaller command:

```
python -m PyInstaller --noconfirm --noconsole --onedir --clean --icon "/Users/ugn/Documents/Code/Commercial/overtitle/overtitle-build/favicon.icns" --add-data "/Users/ugn/Documents/Code/Commercial/overtitle/overtitle-build/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/iso639:iso639/" --add-data "/Users/ugn/Documents/Code/Commercial/overtitle/overtitle-build/templates:templates/" --add-data "/Users/ugn/Documents/Code/Commercial/overtitle/overtitle-build/static:static/" main.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using PyInstaller in one file mode, the app unzips all the data to a temporary folder before the app runs, the delay is that happening. [See here](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html).

This can be fixed by not using onefile mode, or trying another Python to exe program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Thats a bit unfortunate behavior for an app. I’m trying to find the best way to ship my app to multiple machines/customers. Using onedir mode definitely means they would have to receive the app and the directory right? That feels unusual or are there ways to pack those files in an installer? Also could you recommend other python to exe/app options? I’ve tried some but never really achieved a good result so far.

Comment: Also I get how it takes time to unzip and run the app but opening the app then closing then reopening seems like rather buggy behavior to me ?

Comment: @UGN The opening and closing behaviour may be a bug or something, it might be worth checking out the PyInstaller GitHub. Other options such as CXFreeze and Nuitka might be worth checking out. If you use something like InnoSetup to create a setup program for your app, you could get similar functionality to onefile mode.

Comment: thanks again fgo, I'll explore those options ;)